# using putExtra and hasExtra for send and fetch multiple values

Tags: java, android

I have a Recycleview of multiple movie's poster. I tried to click each poster to start a new activity with details of the movie, now I've tried to use the details of movie like date and name of movie to be shared in detail activity so I used this code in MainActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(String MovieName, String MovieDate) {
        Context context = this;
        Class destinationClass = DetailActivity.class;
        Intent intentToStartDetailActivity = new Intent(context, destinationClass);
        intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, String.valueOf(MovieName));
        intentToStartDetailActivity.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, String.valueOf(MovieDate));
        startActivity(intentToStartDetailActivity);
    }
```

and in DetailActivity:

```
mMovieName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_Name);
        mMovieDate = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_movie_date);

        Intent intentThatStartedThisActivity = getIntent();

        if (intentThatStartedThisActivity != null) {
            if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT )) {
                movieName = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                mMovieName.setText(movieName);
            }
            if (intentThatStartedThisActivity.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC )) {
                movieDate = intentThatStartedThisActivity.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC);
                mMovieDate.setText(movieDate);
            }
        }
```

It works fine and I get the information in detail activity but I used Intent.EXTRA_TEXT and Intent.EXTRA_CC and I need to use more. So, my question is can I rename the EXTRA_ with some other word that I choose? Cuz I saw it when I search different names for Extra but don't know how to create a new one like Extra_DESCRIPTION.
And the second question - is it true to use a new if condition with hasExtra() like I did to get information? can't I use only on if condition with hasExtra() to get all information? if so then how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ofcourse you can use any key you like.

for example

```
intent.putExtra("username", yourUsername);
intent.putExtra("password", yourPassword);
```

and it's a good practice to check `intent.hasExtra(String key)` to avoid null pointer exception.
or you can just directly check if intent has any extra budle by `intent.hasExtras()`

Comment: I'm going to try it today and go back to you